Problem parsing Open Ai's API into Zapier (Syntax Error)
I havn't been on here in a while but im in a real pickle here im working on a zap that sends whatsapps of my emails summerized but for some reason i keep getting syntax errors and i cant seem to find the error i swear im not dumb ive been looking for the error for the last hours and even asked chatgpt and it didnt help i wrong it another way the first time i got a syntax error on line 8 and the second on line 9 Ill put the code under
So my question is can someone identify the problem?
Error message
P.s. sorry for my English its not my first language
First:
!pip install openai
import openai

openai.api_key = ''

def summarize_text(text):
    try:
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=text,
            max_tokens=150
        )
        return response.choices[0].text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {e}"

if 'input_data' in locals() and 'email_content' in input_data:
    email_content = input_data['email_content']
    summarized_text = summarize_text(email_content)
    return {'summarized_text': summarized_text}
else:
    return {'error': 'No email content provided'}

Second:
!pip install openai

import openai

openai.api_key = ""

prompt = """Summarize the email content: """

response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="davinci",  # Use the Davinci model
    prompt=prompt,  # Set the prompt for the text completion
    max_tokens=100,  # Limit the response to 100 tokens
    n=1,  # Generate 1 response
    stop=None,  # Don't stop the completion at a specific token
)

output_text = response.choices[0].text

output = {"output_text": output_text}


Of course this is the error message thanks for trying to help out Failed to create a run python in Code by Zapier
Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 9)

No this is the code i pasted into zapiers "run python in code by zapier" step

This will not work as external libraries cannot be installed into Code by Zapier steps such as openai. The only external library that is pre-installed is requests.
